# Editing a point cloud in Three.js

Tags: three.js, particle-system, plas.io

I am trying to customize a 3d point cloud rendering tool.It is available [here](https://github.com/verma/plasio). Going through its code, I could figure out that it makes use of ParticleSystem from Three.js. My objective is to use customize this tool such that user can do following:

- Select objects rendered in the 3d point cloud scene
- Add elements to the scene, like lines, boxes etc.
- Check if objects intersect

Going through some online stuff on Three.js's ParticleSystem, it seems that particle system needs to be initialized right at start of creating it. If that is the case, then it seems editing it is not possible.

Is it anyhow possible to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

ParticleSystem is just "Points" 3D object (PointCloud earlier).

You need to create THREE.BufferGeometry with no points at the beginning and initialize your object with this geometry.

You can modify objects geometry whenever you want using obj.geometry "position" buffer attribute. You just need to mark it with needsUpdate = true after modification. The same technique can be used for updating individual point color and size. But you need to use shader material for your particle system to accomplish individual point color/size control.